# "This is very worrying" vs "This is very worried"?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

An English teacher has told us today that

> "this is very worrying"

is the correct form but

> "this is very worried"

is the incorrect one.

I think that the first one is the best way to tell about a situation or something, which could be the cause of concern or anxiety.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"This is very worrying" means that something (usually a situation) is a worrying one, and is the correct one to use in this case.

"This is very worried" means that a particular thing *is* worried. You usually wouldn't use this, because the word "this" would *usually* refer to an inanimate object, and inanimate objects usually can't have feelings! Unless, of course, you are talking about your electronic pillow which can change mood depending on the weather. Or else it might just refer to non-human beings that don't have names or which aren't personified (such as animals which you don't know or aren't pets of anyone whom you know). Otherwise, one would usually use "he" or "she" to refer to the animal. (Though one would generally use "it" to refer to an unknown animal, not "this.")

Comment: Not quite. *Worry* has another meaning, to be gnawed or pawed by an animal. *This is very worried* means that this (whatever it is) has been mauled by an animal.

Comment: That would definitely be a better "translation" then!

Answer (score 1):

The two phrases have different meanings. "This is very worrying" could be used in a bad situation where the speaker is worried about what is happening and is more likely to be a real thing that someone would say. "This is very worried" would more likely be "he/she/it is very worried," but anyway, it could be used if the speaker were holding or pointing out a worried animal or something.